# run select or delete all

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

How can I run a script or a select to all postgres databases.
maybe with a cursor?

I get the bbdd like this:

```
select * from pg_database
```

The final idea is something like this:

```
delete * from table1 where database in (select basename from pg_database)
```

obs: all databases have the "table1",

Comment: You cannot do that in a single query. You need a separate session (connection) for each database.

Comment: Thanks, check in several forums and I think it is a limitation of the database.

Comment: you can write a shell script that does multiple connections via `psql`

Answer (score 0):

you can write a shell script that does multiple connections via `psql`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
HOST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DBS=`echo 'select datname from pg_database where datname like $$%thing%$$;' |psql -h $HOST --tuples-only`
for DB in $DBS
do
 psql -a -h $HOST -d $DB -c 'delete * from table1'
done
```